# Ensure_inclusion_of keeps passing when it should fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, shoulda

I'm using [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) and [Rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) for testing.

When I try this in my test spec it keeps passing when I haven't done the validations in the model:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:private).in_array(%w[true false]) }
```

The attribute is a boolean that is either true or false:

```
validates_inclusion_of :private, :in => [true, false]
```

How would I write this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`True` and `False` are not strings so don't use %w.

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:private).in_array([true, false]) }
```

**Update - 10th Apr 2014**

This validation will not work in current versions of Shoulda and, as per [this recent commit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/5b44edf8b31006724b2864037002f73c09e608cf), it will not be fixed but will instead raise an exception.

As any value assigned to a boolean field will be cast to either true (set by `true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'`) or false (set by anything else) my preferred approach for testing a boolean field is as follows:

- For a boolean that allows nulls in the database - no test is required, any possible value will be valid
- For a boolean that does not allow nulls in the database - use `it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:field)` which will pass when the `validates :field, inclusion: { in: [true,false] }` is set on the model